# Makefile pattern to compile all source files to executables

Tags: makefile

I want my makefile to identify and build every source file in the directory.

Both .f files and their executables exists in the current directory. All source files are short, independent pieces (no linking to each other). I want executables to be named the same as the source files sans .f (foo.f -> foo)

The following does not work:

```
FC=gfortran

% :: %.f
    ${FC} -Wall $< -o $@
```

When I run Make I get 
`make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

How can I get make to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The following makefile does what I want:

```
FC=gfortran
FFLAGS=-Wall

SRC = $(wildcard *.f)
EXE = $(SRC:.f=)

all : $(EXE)
```